# Warnings C26415 / C26418 when passing a COM interface smart pointer to a function

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, com, smart-pointers, code-analysis

Here is the definition of a function:

```
void CMSATools::SetPublisherDatesNotAvailable(MSAToolsLibrary::IAvailabilityPtr pAvailability, 
                                              std::vector<COleDateTime>& rVectorDates, 
                                              DWORD dwNumDates)
{
}
```

The parameter `MSAToolsLibrary::IAvailabilityPtr` is designed like this:

`_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IAvailability, __uuidof(IAvailability));`

This code (smart pointer) is all constructed automatically as part of the COM interface. But I am receiving two warnings about using it as a parameter to my own function:

- [C26415](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiK1-3livjzAhXbEcAKHTSVCgEQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fcpp%2Fcode-quality%2Fc26415&usg=AOvVaw3zoEfb3ETUXcwE6Yb894yL) 530 Smart pointer parameter 'pAvailability' is used only to access contained pointer. Use T* or T& instead (r.30).

I understand this much from the linked article:

> Using a smart pointer type to pass data to a function indicates that
> the target function needs to manage the lifetime of the contained
> object. However, if the function only uses the smart pointer to access
> the contained object and never actually calls any code that may lead
> to its deallocation (that is, never affect its lifetime), there is
> usually no need to complicate the interface with smart pointers. A
> plain pointer or reference to the contained object is preferred.

All my function does is use the pointer like this:

`throw_if_fail(pAvailability->SetDatesNotAvailable(arr.parray));`

The other warning is:

- [C26418](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26418?view=msvc-160) 530 Shared pointer parameter 'pAvailability' is not copied or moved. Use T* or T& instead (r.36).

I notice it says:

> If shared pointer parameter is passed by value or reference to a
> constant object it is expected that function will take control of its
> target object’s lifetime without affecting of the caller. The code
> should either copy or move the shared pointer parameter to another
> shared pointer object or pass it further to other code by invoking
> functions which accept shared pointers. If this is not the case, then
> plain pointer or reference may be feasible.

Here is a snippet of my usage of the function (not real code as such):

```
MSAToolsLibrary::IAvailabilityPtr pAvailability = NULL;
throw_if_fail(pPublisher->get_Availability(&pAvailability));
if (pAvailability != NULL)
{
    std::vector<COleDateTime> vectorDates;
    const DWORD dwNumDates = InitDatesNotAvailableVector(vectorDates);
    theApp.MSAToolsInterface().SetPublisherDatesNotAvailable(pAvailability, vectorDates, dwNumDates);
}
```

I tried:

`void SetPublisherDatesNotAvailable(T* pAvailability, std::vector<COleDateTime>& rVectorDates, DWORD dwNumDates);`

And it said I had a syntax error.

Comment: I think what it says is that, passing a smart pointer by value triggers an unnecessary AddRef/Release. Instead, the function could take a raw COM interface pointer, `IAvailability*` (may need `MSAToolsLibrary::IAvailability*`). The call site should work unchanged, there's an implicit conversion operator on `_com_ptr_t` that returns the raw pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Alright, I will try later this morning and get back to you.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That worked. All I had to do was then add a `if` test to check if the pointer was null.

Comment: Igor's explanation is correct, and transliterates the suggestions made in the code analysis documentation to match. Things are different here, though: This warning isn't about correctness. It is *purely* a performance optimization, and may open up the opportunity for future defects. If I find a bit of time I'll see if I can have a look and see whether the suggestion does indeed have adverse effects.

Comment: @IInspectable Alright! At the moment I have it as explained by Igor. Please tag me if you find anything out that warrents a reverting to `IAvailabilityPtr` again.

Comment: You should think about your APIs. If you are passing around simple values like int, double, long, etc, then generally you can pass by value. If you are passing around classes/structs, then carefully consider making them pass by reference. Make them const reference if you don't want the original object to change, or just regular reference if it is ok for it to change. Pass by pointer if it's possible the object might be null or you want to get an object back. There are hundreds of articles like this: https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I get you. But this is a COM API interface and it provides the smart pointer that I was supposed to use. So I assumed that it was that smart pointer that I was supposed to pass to my own method. In all honesty, I did not realise at the time that this variable was a smart pointer. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is rather involved. While it's easy to explain the code analysis diagnostic, coming up with a mitigation strategy boils down to choosing between the lesser of several evils.

### COM Fundamentals

COM models the concept of shared ownership. Every interface keeps track of the number of outstanding references, and the COM object implementing that interface is destroyed when the reference count reaches zero. Lifetime management is exposed through the [`IUnknown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nn-unknwn-iunknown) interface with its `AddRef()` and `Release()` members, that increment and decrement the reference count, respectively.

### Smarter COM

While lifetime management can be implemented manually, explicitly accessing the `IUnknown` interface, this is as tedious as it is easy to get wrong. Smart pointer types (such as [`_com_ptr_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class)) fill in that gap by providing automatic resource management. To that end the `_com_ptr_t` class template implements the following five special member functions: copy and move constructors, copy and move assignment operators, and a destructor. Each of these add calls to `AddRef()` and `Release()` as appropriate<sup>1</sup>. Those calls are invisible, so it's important to know that they are there.

### Motivating Example

To keep this answer self-contained, let's write a simple program that outputs the RGB color of the desktop. It exhibits the same code analysis diagnostics but is sufficiently compact to illustrate possible solutions:

```cpp
#include <ShObjIdl_core.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <comip.h>

#include <iostream>

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IDesktopWallpaper, __uuidof(IDesktopWallpaper));

COLORREF background_color(IDesktopWallpaperPtr wallpaper)  // line 10
{
    COLORREF cr {};
    _com_util::CheckError(wallpaper->GetBackgroundColor(&cr));
    return cr;
}

int main()
{
    _com_util::CheckError(::CoInitialize(nullptr));

    IDesktopWallpaperPtr spWallpaper { nullptr };
    _com_util::CheckError(spWallpaper.CreateInstance(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper));

    auto const color { background_color(spWallpaper) };
    std::wcout << L"R: " << GetRValue(color)
               << L"\tG: " << GetGValue(color)
               << L"\tB: " << GetBValue(color) << std::endl;
}
```

Running this through code analysis produces the following output:

> main.cpp(10): warning C26415: Smart pointer parameter 'wallpaper' is used only to access contained pointer. Use T* or T& instead (r.30).
> main.cpp(10): warning C26418: Shared pointer parameter 'wallpaper' is not copied or moved. Use T* or T& instead (r.36).

Bear in mind that the code shown above is perfectly valid. There is nothing inherently wrong with it. Every expression is well defined, all resources are properly managed, and all error cases are handled.

### Code Analysis, er, Analysis

[C26418](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26418) is more important here (even though [C26415](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26415) is advertised as the priority issue). The code analyzer recognizes `_com_ptr_t` as a smart pointer type but sees that none of the special functions (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment) are used. It thus concludes that no lifetime management is happening through the smart pointer type, and recommends to use a raw pointer/reference instead.

The observation is accurate, and the suggestion is mostly fine, too, with just one wrinkle (see below).

### Applying the Suggested Fix

The suggested fix is to *"use `T*` or `T&` instead"*. With `_com_ptr_t` providing implicit conversion operators to [`Interface&` and `Interface*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-extractors) there's a choice we have to make. Luckily, this is one of the few choices with a clear winner.

Using `T*`

```cpp
COLORREF background_color(IDesktopWallpaper* wallpaper)
{
    if (wallpaper)
    {
        COLORREF cr {};
        _com_util::CheckError(wallpaper->GetBackgroundColor(&cr));
        return cr;
    }
    else
    {
        _com_issue_error(E_POINTER);
    }
}
```

Using `T&`

```cpp
COLORREF background_color(IDesktopWallpaper& wallpaper)
{
    COLORREF cr {};
    _com_util::CheckError(wallpaper.GetBackgroundColor(&cr));
    return cr;
}
```

The call site (`background_color(spWallpaper)`) doesn't need to be changed, and exhibits identical behavior with either function call. The function implementations are different owed to the different semantics of `operator Interface&()` and `operator Interface*()` of `_com_ptr_t`. The former performs a null pointer check, whereas the latter doesn't, passing that responsibility on to the function implementation.

Unless you have *very* specific reasons to allow passing a null pointer (e.g. if you require `noexcept`) the implementation taking an interface reference is superior: It establishes stronger preconditions, and fails fast if the preconditions are violated. Personally, I'm a big fan of particularly the latter.

### Victory

So then, that solves both code analysis warnings. Everything's good, right? Right!?

Well, no. Not really. While the code analyzer is pretty good at identifying smart pointer types, it also makes the assumption, that **all** lifetime management is handled through the smart pointer's special member functions. `_com_ptr_t` does not establish that invariant, as can be seen here:

```cpp
COLORREF background_color(IDesktopWallpaper& wallpaper)
{
    COLORREF cr {};
    _com_util::CheckError(wallpaper.GetBackgroundColor(&cr));
    wallpaper.Release();  // My name is Pointer, Dangling Pointer
    return cr;
}
```

There's no beating around the bush, this is bad. This function *borrows* a reference to a COM object, but then goes on to call `wallpaper.Release()` as if it owned it, decrementing the reference count (that was never upped!). In the sample above, this is the only reference, and when the caller (the `main` function) tries to clean up it accesses memory through a pointer that no longer points to valid memory. The best case scenario is an access violation, that eventually terminates the program. In a more complex program, however, this is an instant heap corruption bug.

Code analysis warnings, you ask? None. Arguably, this is a defect in the code analyzer that, while identifying `_com_ptr_t` as a smart pointer, plays the Alzheimer's card when it comes to recalling COM lifetime management semantics.

### Solutions?

There aren't any, to my knowledge, that are all-around safe. Nothing that can be verified statically, and ages well with the code in face of future changes. My personal take is to always pass COM interface pointers wrapped behind smart pointers **by value**.

This is going to be controversial, since passing a `_com_ptr_t` by value is going to incur a copy, that's not always strictly required. Invoking the [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-com-ptr-t) causes a call to `AddRef()` on the contained interface pointer. On function exit the copy bound to the parameter is destroyed, and the destructor calls `Release()` on the contained interface pointer. This may seem like an artificial reference count bump, which is, again, not strictly required.

There are good reasons to do this still:

- It enables local reasoning: Any function that accepts a `_com_ptr_t` by value *owns* a shared reference for the duration of the function call. It can freely copy it, or pass it along, and be confident that code outside the function cannot invalidate the interface pointer (modulo bugs).
- It allows opting out of automatic resource management. Since the function owns a reference, it can, for example, [`Detach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-detach) the interface pointer and pass it to someone that takes ownership.
- It continues to work with C++20 coroutines. In the times before C++20 it was near impossible to invalidate references passed into functions. A reference to a local object was, for all intents and purposes, valid for the entire duration of a function call, regardless of how deep that call stack got. Coroutines change all that, and references can get invalidated at the first suspension point of a coroutine. Passing a smart pointer by value is immune to local object invalidation midway through a coroutine.

Personally, I would opt to disable the code analysis warnings here, and go with the following implementation:

```cpp
#pragma warning(suppress : 26415 26418)
COLORREF background_color(IDesktopWallpaperPtr wallpaper)
{
    COLORREF cr {};
    _com_util::CheckError(wallpaper->GetBackgroundColor(&cr));
    return cr;
}
```

Mind you, this by itself, isn't all that great either. There's still the glaring issue that you *can* call `wallpaper->Release()`, leading to the same issue as with the version that takes an interface reference. And no code analysis rule to warn you.

There's still some manual work involved in making this safe, i.e. finding and removing all explicit calls to `AddRef()` and `Release()`. Neither one is required when using smart pointers (much like `new` and `delete` aren't), and either one is a potential bug.

### Conclusion

The situation here isn't great, and there's no single solution that can address all concerns. There's a lot to read through, and even more to consider. And by the end of the day it's up to you to decide which poison to pick. Sorry.

---

<sup>1</sup> *The move constructor and move assignment operator are special in that they transfer ownership. Neither one calls `AddRef()` or `Release()` on their respective argument, as there is no change in reference counts. The interface pointer is merely moved into a new home.*

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I have reverted to `IAvailabilityPtr` and imlemented the `__pragma`.

Comment: You should use the regular `#pragma` syntax, though. The alternative syntax `__pragma` is meant for cases where you cannot use the regular syntax, i.e. when a pragma appears inside a preprocessor macro where `#` is the stringizing operator.

Comment: But it was used on one of the answers on here as the preferred way so I adopted it for all of them.

Comment: Not sure why it was recommended and less so why it would be the preferred way. It's a non-standard [Microsoft-specific extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword). It was introduced to solve a single problem: Inability to use `#pragma` inside preprocessor macros. Avoid it if you can.